# ASP Web API Ajax Post Request HTTP Error 415

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to learn the Web API from ASP.NET and wanted to do a little todo list.

All works in swagger but if I want to do a post request in ajax I get an "415 Unsupported Media Type" error.

My Ajax Call:

```
function sendTodoTitle() {
            $.ajax({
               url: url + "/api/todo/sendTitle",
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "JSON",
               data: JSON.stringify({todoItem: textIn.val()}),
               success: function(data) {
                   valData(data);
               }
            });
        }
```

url does indeed work so it's not an issue because of the url.
textIn also works like it should. (an )

My Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase {
    InFSTodo fs = new InFSTodo();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<String> Post() {
        return Ok(fs.GetJSON());
    }

    [HttpPost("sendTitle")]
    public ActionResult<String> Post([FromBody] String todoItem) {
        var list = fs.Get();
        list.Add(new Todo(list.Count, todoItem));
        fs.Store(list);

        return Ok(list.ToJson());
    }
```

From previous questions which are askes here I got following:

- For primitive datatypes use [FromBody]
- ASP.NET want JSON data to be sent

I hope someone can help me here, because I already tried a full and a half day on this
I appreciate any help!

Edit:

InFSTodo.cs:

```
 public class InFSTodo {
    string fileName = "todo.json";

    /// <summary>
    /// Store the JSON in file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The list of todos to be stored</param>
    public void Store(List<Todo> list) {
        string json = list.ToJson(); // ToJson() <-- Extension Method

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            File.CreateText(fileName).Close();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        sw.Write(json);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the JSON from file and convert to List of todos
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of todos</returns>
    public List<Todo> Get() {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return new List<Todo>();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string json = "";

        while(sr.Peek() != -1) 
            json += sr.ReadLine();

        sr.Close();

        return ListExtension.FromJSON(json); // <-- No possibillity for static Extension Methods
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the JSON from file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>JSON as string</returns>
    public String GetJSON() {
        return Get().ToJson();
    }
}
```

TodoController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase {
    InFSTodo fs = new InFSTodo();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<String> Post() {
        return Ok(fs.GetJSON());
    }

    [HttpPost("sendTitle")]
    public ActionResult<String> Post(String todoItem) {
        var list = fs.Get();
        list.Add(new Todo(list.Count, todoItem));
        fs.Store(list);

        return Ok(list.ToJson());
    }

    [HttpPost("deleteTodo")]
    public ActionResult<String> Post(int id) {
        var list = fs.Get();
        list.Remove(list.Find(item => item.Id == id));
        fs.Store(list);

        return Ok(list.ToJson());
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<String> PostDone(int id) {
        var list = fs.Get();
        var todo = list.Find(item => item.Id == id);

        if (todo != null)
            todo.WasDone = true;
        else
            return StatusCode(422); // 422 Unprocessable Entity

        fs.Store(list);

        return Ok(list.ToJson());
    }
}
```

Todo.cs:

```
[Serializable]
public class Todo {
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public bool WasDone { get; set; }

    public Todo(int id, String title) {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        WasDone = false;
    }

    public void ChangeID(Todo second) {
        int id = Id;
        Id = second.Id;
        second.Id = id;
    }
}
```

The error message after Serge Reply:

[image]

Error in postman:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this ajax

```
function sendTodoTitle() {
            $.ajax({
               url: url + "/api/todo/sendTitle",
               type: "POST",
               data: {todoItem: textIn.val()},
               success: function(data) {
                   valData(data);
               }
            });
        }
```

and remove [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost("sendTitle")]
 public ActionResult<String> Post( string todoItem) {
```

Comment: After I edited all like you said, I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) error, do you know why?

Comment: You have a bug in your code . Could you post InFSTodo and Todo clasess for the start?

Comment: I edited my question, now there are all relevant classes in it

Comment: Thanks, and can you post the whole 500 error message too?

Comment: Did it, line 32 is the ajax call itself

Comment: Did you try to use Postman? It usually brings much better error message.

Comment: I didn't
I'll try

Comment: I tried to do it in postman and added a screenshot to my question. Hopefully it was what you wanted because I'm new to postman

Comment: This error maybe anywhere. It is out of the question. I answered your question already. Now you can post another question about your 500 error.